# Which vector posseses the nearest lower value?

Tags: r, performance, vector

**Goal**

Given 3 vectors `A`, `B` and `x`, I would like to get a vector `Sol` stating `TRUE` every time the nearest lower value of `A` and `B` united comes from `A` and `FALSE` if it comes form `B`.

**Information about the data**

- `A` is a relatively short (~80 elements) vector of integers.
- `B` is a relatively short (~200 elements) vector of integers.
- `x` is a very long (1e7-1e8 maybe) vector of integers.

**Example Data**

These data are much shorter than the one I am to

```
set.seed(31)
while(TRUE)
{
   A = floor(runif(30, 1,1e5))
   B = c(1,floor(runif(80, 1,1e5)))
   if (!any(c(A %in% B, B %in% A))){break}
}
x = floor(runif(300, 1,1e5))
```

**Non-performent solution**

The following should work however it will be very slow as `x` become very long.

```
Sol = rep(NA,length(x))
for (i in 1:length(x))
{
   xi = x[i]
   mA = max(A[A<=xi])
   mB = max(B[B<=xi])
   if (mA>mB) {Sol[i]=TRUE} else {Sol[i]=FALSE}
}
```

**Note on performance**

The process will be repeated maybe 1000 times. I currently don't have accurate estimation of the number of repeats and the length of `x` though.

---

## Benchmark @MaratTalipov answer in comparison with mine

```
set.seed(31)
while(TRUE)
{
   A = floor(runif(100, 1,1e6))
   B = c(1,floor(runif(300, 1,1e6)))
   if (!any(c(A %in% B, B %in% A))){break}
}
x = floor(runif(1e5, 1,1e6))


Marat = function (A,B,x)
{
    d <- rbind(data.frame(x=TRUE,y=A),data.frame(x=FALSE,y=B))
    d <- d[order(d$y),]
    return (d$x[findInterval(x,d$y)])
}
Remi = function (A,B,x)
{
    Sol = rep(NA,length(x))
    for (i in 1:length(x))
    {
       xi = x[i]
       mA = max(A[A<=xi])
       mB = max(B[B<=xi])
       if (mA>mB) {Sol[i]=TRUE} else {Sol[i]=FALSE}
    }
}


benchmark(s1 <- Marat(A,B,x), s2 <- Remi(A,B,x), order="elapsed")

               test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1 s1 <- Marat(A, B, x)       100   1.003       NA     0.964    0.065          0         0
2 s2 <- Remi(A, B, x)        100 144.118       NA   130.320   14.867          0         0
```

Comment: `vapply(x, function(y) max(A[A <= y]) > max(B[B <= y]), NA)` is more readable, not a huge gain in performance though

Comment: @rawr, it should be a huge gain because your code doesn't copy `Sol` (which is potentially very long) at each iteration

Comment: Oh sure I did not think about that. Well I could have pre-assigned the memory for `Sol` (question now edited). I was mainly trying to avoid looping in R.

Comment: Yes, although that gain can be achieved by pre-allocating Sol to be a vector equal in size to x.

Comment: @Remi.b - you probably better initializing it with NA's instead of FALSE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this approach:

```
d <- rbind(data.frame(x=TRUE,y=A),data.frame(x=FALSE,y=B))
d <- d[order(d$y),]
out <- d$x[findInterval(x,d$y)]
```

Comment: You might want to replace `F` by `FALSE` and `T` by `TRUE`. Seems to work nicely. I'll wait a little bit to see other suggestions and will then check your answer. Thanks. +1

Comment: @Remi.b, If you had a chance, could you do some benchmarking of the solutions in this post?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this approach (apply family of functions). It still has to loop through all values of x, so there is no avoiding linear scan, but much more efficient than straight loops. I added an additional condition where value of x is below all values of A or B and return NA in this case. You can remove it if you want NULLs instead.

```
sapply(x, function(x) if (x < min(A) || x < min(B)) NA else if (max(A[A <= x]) > max(B[B <= x])) TRUE else FALSE)
```

Comment: you dont need the second if since it's already a logical operation `sapply(x, function(x) if (x < min(A) || x < min(B)) NA else (max(A[A <= x]) > max(B[B <= x])))`

Comment: Good point and agree. Thank you. I had not thought of making it crisper. :)